# Drupal - Install module - Access denied in administrator

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

**Context** : I'm working on a Drupal 8 project and want to add new modules.

**Problem**: when I try to install new module through the web interface (logged as admin user), I get the error message:

> Access denied, You are not authorized to access this page.

The problem I have is exactly the same as this [problem](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2764541#comment-13517707). However, there are no clear solutions. I tried to play with `allow_authorize_operations` parameters in `setting.php` file, `.htaccess` file and files permissions without success.

After reading this similar [issue](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-04-03/access-denied-when-trying-to-change-theme), I suspect the problem is about the `.htaccess` or the `site.conf` file. I'm not confortable with these 2 files and suspect I'm missing something:

---

Edit: I founded this interesting [discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2612160). They highlight in comment [#35](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2612160#comment-11869254) also a similar issue. The problems might come from the fact that the `index.php` belongs to the `web` folder. To clean the URL, I apply the following in root directory:

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

**All files**:
`web/.htaccess`

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Add correct encoding for SVGZ.
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

# Most of the following PHP settings cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and
# Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::bootEnvironment() for settings that can be
# changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
  # PHP 5.6 has deprecated $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and produces warnings if this is
  # not set.
  php_value always_populate_raw_post_data   -1
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Set a fallback resource if mod_rewrite is not enabled. This allows Drupal to
# work without clean URLs. This requires Apache version >= 2.2.16. If Drupal is
# not accessed by the top level URL (i.e.: http://example.com/drupal/ instead of
# http://example.com/), the path to index.php will need to be adjusted.
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  FallbackResource /index.php
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  # RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/foo will be redirected to http://www.example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/foo will be redirected to http://example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /web

  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Redirect common PHP files to their new locations.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(install.php) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(rebuild.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core
  RewriteRule ^ %1/core/%2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  # Rewrite install.php during installation to see if mod_rewrite is working
  RewriteRule ^core/install.php core/install.php?rewrite=ok [QSA,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # For security reasons, deny access to other PHP files on public sites.
  # Note: The following URI conditions are not anchored at the start (^),
  # because Drupal may be located in a subdirectory. To further improve
  # security, you can replace '!/' with '!^/'.
  # Allow access to PHP files in /core (like authorize.php or install.php):
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/[^/]*\.php$
  # Allow access to test-specific PHP files:
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/system/tests/https?.php
  # Allow access to Statistics module's custom front controller.
  # Copy and adapt this rule to directly execute PHP files in contributed or
  # custom modules or to run another PHP application in the same directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/statistics/statistics.php$
  # Deny access to any other PHP files that do not match the rules above.
  # Specifically, disallow autoload.php from being served directly.
  RewriteRule "^(.+/.*|autoload)\.php($|/)" - [F]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Various header fixes.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  # Disable Proxy header, since it's an attack vector.
  RequestHeader unset Proxy
</IfModule>
```

Or the `site.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName domain.fr
        ServerAlias www.domain.fr

        DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project
        <Directory /var/www/my_project>
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.fr [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.fr
</VirtualHost>
```

At the end of the `settings.php`, I add:

```
if (isset($GLOBALS['request']) and
    '/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME')) {
        $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

**Note:**

- The installation of new module using `composer` is working.
- I replicated the project on my local machine (Windows) and the installation process is working.
- In the reports logs, after I tried to upload a module through the web interface, there is the following message:

```
Type        access denied
Date        Saturday 21 March 2020 - 15:12
User        Anonymous (not verified)
Location    http://www.domain.fr/web/core/authorize.php/
Referrer    http://www.domain.fr/admin/modules/install
Message     authorize.php
Importance  Avertissement
```

- In the above report, there is the `web` folder appearing in the location path

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings on the site's status page? (/admin/reports/status)

Comment: Neither warning nor error message, everything is up to date !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post it as a solution as it might help someone later.

The problem comes from the project structure. The `DocumentRoot` in the `site.conf` was pointing to the drupal root folder. However, since the `web/index.php` belongs to the `web` directory, I add an `.htaccess` in the root folder to redirect to the `web` folder.

The **solution** was:

- Delete `.htaccess` file at drupal root folder
- Update `DocumentRoot` path in the `site.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project/web
<Directory /var/www/my_project/web>
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

- Restart apache server: `service apache2 reload`